# number pattern matching in Teradata

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I was trying to get the rows matched with a pattern by using like in Teradata

```
select * from table_name where col_name like '10%';
```

here I wanted to get all the rows with column values like 1000, 101, 109, 1048
this is showing me error:

> *** Failure 3544 Partial string matching requires character operands.
> Statement# 1, Info =0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may first cast your numeric column to `VARCHAR` and then do the `LIKE` comparison:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CAST(col_name AS VARCHAR(30)) LIKE '10%';
```